# SQLiteException: no such column: date (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, name, date FROM member

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm working with database, and I the following data class

datahelper.java

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "create table "
        + TABLE_MEMBER + "(" + MEMBER_ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + MEMBER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + MEMBER_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

and it point the error code to this two java file

SQLController.java

```
 public Cursor readData() {
        String[] allColumns = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID,DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME,DBhelper.MEMBER_DATE};
        Cursor c = database.query(DBhelper.TABLE_MEMBER, allColumns,null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
       }
        return c;
    }
```

Mainactivity.java

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dbcon = new SQLController(this);
        dbcon.open();
        addmem_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addmem_bt_id);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.memberList_id);

        addmem_bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent add_mem = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add_member.class);
                startActivity(add_mem);
            }
        });

        // Attach The Data From DataBase Into ListView Using Crusor Adapter
        Cursor cursor = dbcon.readData();
        String[] from = new String[] { DBhelper.MEMBER_ID, DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME, DBhelper.MEMBER_DATE };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.member_id, R.id.member_name, R.id.member_date};
```

thx all your help

Comment: What are the values of the constants `DBhelper.MEMBER_ID`, `DBhelper.MEMBER_NAME`, `DBhelper.MEMBER_DATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date is a function in sqlite, I suspect you cant use as column name or alias

Comment: That  shouldn't matter.  There's a list of keywords at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html that you have to escape if you want to use them as a column name, but `date` isn't on it.

Comment: because is a function, not a reserved word https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: i have rename the date to "event" and its work, but i compile the apps the error still appear  the apps can still can run.
now i facing another problem, when i modify the data i jst added in, my member  name colum data succesful  changed, bt the new data of the event column data move to member name column and combine together. The event column is still remain the old data.
example:
member name column : abc ; event column : 123.      I modify to cde and 456, after click modify button then become member name colum:cde456,event:123 .   sry for my bad explanation